# How to add custom text next to the title of the window's preview tab? — Windows 10

Tags: windows, tabs, autohotkey, taskbar

**I'm looking for adding custom text here:**
[image]

This may be helpful for me to add quick *short descriptions* on what I'm doing on each window. Also I'm looking for adding color tags, but, to be specific for now, how could I add text here?

**What API or command allows me to add *custom text* next to the title of the *window preview tab*?** — Windows 10

I will use [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) in writing the main script to achieve this.

Comment: With Windows API you could call `FindWindow("TaskListOverlayWnd",NULL)` to get a handle of the thumbnail window. You could position a layered window on top of that to display your custom text. A windows or WinEvent hook could be of use to track changes in the visibility of the thumbnail window. Don't know how to do that with AutoHotkey though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple solution:

```
#Persistent

title1 = Sf
title2 = QkRfit

title1a = Sf || my description for Sf
title2a = QkRfit || my description for QkRfit

SetTimer ChangeTitle, 50
return

ChangeTitle:
SetTitleMatchMode, 3
If (WinExist("ahk_class TaskListThumbnailWnd") || MouseIsOver("ahk_class TaskListThumbnailWnd"))
{
    WinSetTitle, %title1% ahk_class CabinetWClass,, %title1a%
    WinSetTitle, %title2% ahk_class CabinetWClass,, %title2a%
}
else
{
    WinSetTitle, %title1a% ahk_class CabinetWClass,, %title1%
    WinSetTitle, %title2a% ahk_class CabinetWClass,, %title2%
}
return

MouseIsOver(WinTitle) {
 MouseGetPos,,, Window
 return WinExist(WinTitle . " ahk_id " . Window)
}
```